# String slicing / string manipulation in PHP

Tags: php, substr, strpos

```
Total accesses: 296282 - Total Traffic: 1.2 GB
CPU Usage: u757.94 s165.33 cu0 cs0 - 2.56% CPU load
8.22 requests/sec - 33.5 kB/second - 4175 B/request
22 requests currently being processed, 26 idle workers
```

Let say we have the above as string and we store that string in a variable.
Problem: I want to get the VALUE of the following:

1. requests/sec - CURRENT VALUE IS 8.22
2. requests currently being processed - CURRENT VALUE IS 22
3. idle workers - CURRENT VALUE IS 26

Done some solution using **strpos** and **substr** but i dont think its a good solution at all because those values above are dynamic it could be 2 digits or 4 digits or longer.

**sample code:**

```
$rps = substr($data,strpos($data,"requests/sec")-5,4);
echo $rps; //displays 8.22
```

Is there another way to do this? I will appreciate any response :)

Comment: regex - http://us.php.net/manual/en/book.regex.php

Comment: Or `sscanf` - http://php.net/manual/en/function.sscanf.php

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Regular expressions.

```
$values = array();
preg_match("/(?P<rps>[\d.]+) requests\/sec(.*)(?P<requests>[\d]+) requests (.*)(?P<workers>[\d]+) idle workers/", $your_text, $values);

print 
"requests/sec - CURRENT VALUE IS {$values['rps']}
 requests currently being processed - CURRENT VALUE IS {$values['requests']}
 idle workers - CURRENT VALUE IS {$values['workers']}";
```

Comment: Thank you for the help. I was able to solve the issue with your answer. :)

Answer (score 3):

Regular expression would work:

```
<?php
$data = 'Total accesses: 296282 - Total Traffic: 1.2 GB
CPU Usage: u757.94 s165.33 cu0 cs0 - 2.56% CPU load
8.22 requests/sec - 33.5 kB/second - 4175 B/request
22 requests currently being processed, 26 idle workers';

if( preg_match('/(\d*\.?\d*)\srequests\/sec/', $data, $m) ){
    echo $m[1];
}else{
    echo 'no match';
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the help. I was able to solve the issue with your answer. :)

Answer (score 2):

Assuming all of that output is in string variable $output. You could do this:

```
// requests per second
$regex = '#^([0-9]*\.?[0-9].*)\040requests/sec#';
preg_match($regex, $output, $matches);
$req_per_sec = $matches[1];

// request being processed
$regex = '/([0-9]*)\040requests\040currently/';
preg_match($regex, $output, $matches);
$req_processed = $matches[1];

// idle workers
$regex = '/\040([0-9]*)\040idle\040workers/';
preg_match($regex, $output, $matches);
$idle_workers = $matches[1];
```

Comment: Thank you for the help. I was able to solve the issue with your answer. :)